# Having issues with wxPython (Pheonix) sizes

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am trying to port over a bit of code from wx2.8 to wxPheonix (3.0.3.dev78356 msw). I'm using code from the pyfa project (https://github.com/DarkFenX/Pyfa) which is currently being rewritten for python3. This code takes some concepts from PyCollapsiblePane and implements it better (there are some bugs with PCP). If you download and open pyfa, the collapsible panels are on the right side (resources, resistances, etc) if you want to get a feel for how it is supposed to work.

Anyway, I'm trying to port this over and I cannot seem to get it to work well. I know Pheonix introduces some changes to sizers and how things are resized. I am able to collapse the panel (and have the parent panel fit to the new size), and then open it again. But when I try to collapse it again nothing seems to happen.

Here's what is currently happening:

http://gyazo.com/68717f66c498d850ef60ee83e1c0ae4a

And here is how it's suppposed to work (wxPython 2.8 in the pyfa app)

http://gyazo.com/87cc0f61052dca0e81c387da0f84c0c4

This is the module that I'm working on (the script has a test case if run directly): http://pastebin.com/ghuVGXWN

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove `self.SetMinSize(sz)` from `OnStateChange`, works great now.